# Windows Phone 7 App on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am new to Silverlight and Windows Mobile development and hence the question may sound very naive.

Can Windows Phone 7 application built using Silverlight execute on Windows Mobile 6.5 as well?

Any ideas? Appreciate any help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by [lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336186/lukas), there is **no** Sivlerlight runtime for Windows Mobile. That being said, an application specifically targeting WP7 cannot run on WM due to lack of necessary resources and components.

WM supports [.NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb975138.aspx) and that's pretty much the extent of .NET development you can leverage on that platform.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7 uses version 3.7 of the Compact Framework. Windows Mobile uses 3.5 (or earlier) depending on the version of WM.

Version 3.7 of the compact framework contains breaking differences in the 3 main areas of the framework: UI controls, CLR and APIs.
As these areas are all breaking it is not possible to create an application which runs on both.

It may, however, be possible to create POCOs which contain logic and/or functionality which can run on both.